# Quectel MC60 UART communication

Tags: gsm, uart

I am working with Quectel's MC60 GSM module.I was able to synchronise with MC60 uart port and successfully received "OK" after sending AT commands continiously.But by mistake i set some non standard baud rate and now the module is not responding properly with AT command requests and is only reporting junk characters.I have searched the web about the solution to this problem but didn't got any answers for this.
So can anyone please explain how to revert back to factory settings externally.

Thanks
Amit kumar

Answer (score 0):

Before on check the power, all GSM modules low powered starts responding junk characters. If the baud rate is not the appropriate no characters at all.
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Change the firmware to original one. It will respond to AT commands as mentioned on the manual. Baud rate for serial communication 115200.

Hope it helps you.